# including fully qualified name in documentation

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

When I click short-cut key **Alt+Shift+J**, eclipse adds some java documentation with

```
@author xyz
@since date
```

on top of class.

- So, where can we define this documentation template in eclipse when we click that short-cut key?
- And how can I add additional details to include **fully qualified name** in class documentation in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Window` -> `prefereneces` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Code Templates`. Select `comments` -> `types`. Edit and add the following line there: `${package_name}.${type_name}`. In the code templates there is content assist by the way.