# How to use auto completion in Eclipse adding fully qualified name

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

How can I use auto completion in Eclipse adding fully qualified name?

In order to avoid sonar/checkstyle (Unused Imports) issues, we've got the policy to use the fully qualified name in Javadoc.

I'm looking for a method still using auto completion. Something like pressing Shift-key while using auto completion?

Changing settings always using the fully qualified name is not an option, only required in Javadoc comments.

Comment: i think you are asking for custom templates. Is it?

Comment: No, but thank you. Please see comment I've added at FuryComptuers answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround to your problem, you can configure Eclipse to automatically remove unnecessary imports whenever you are saving a file (Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Save Actions - Configure, then in the Unnecessary Code tab, make sure *Remove unused imports* is checked). Once this is done you can remove the check for unused imports in checkstyle.

I agree this isn't quite what you asked for, but at least you would still make you have no unused imports (assuming everyone on your team configure Eclipse the same way).

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was our first thought as well but we've got another solution. We have found the property `processJavadoc` of the Checkstyle module `UnusedImports` which ignores JavaDoc imports.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the answer described here:

[including fully qualified name in documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748493/including-fully-qualified-name-in-documentation)

"Go to Window -> prefereneces -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates. Select comments -> types. Edit and add the following line there: ${package_name}.${type_name}."

This changes your Javadoc to use the fully qualified name when generated.

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I'm looking for. I wanna use for example `{@link java.lang.Math#sqrt(double)}` instead of `{@link Math#sqrt(double)}`. You can use auto completion in JavaDoc but it never will use the fully qualified name. So I'm looking for a method to use that fully qualified name otherwise I do have an import which is only used by JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

You must disable processing of Javadocs in Eclipse's Java compiler (`Java Compiler -> Javadoc`, topmost checkbox), see here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26792#c10

If I disable it, when I autocomplete class names in Javadocs, I get the fully qualified name.